# How to remove the space between the authentication layout and the rest of the components in Laravel, Vue and Inertia

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm programming in laravel and vue with inertia, so when I authenticate in the system the authentication layout makes a space with the header of the page, how can I solve that

[Here in this image I show the space that I want to eliminate is marked with a red pencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agt5P.png)

[Layout Autentication code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88dS.png)
[Dashboard code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARe2m.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Authenticate Layout file go down almost to the end and in this part of the code

```
<header class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow" v-if="$slots.header">
    <div class="pt-4">
        <slot name="header" />
    </div>
</header>
```

Eliminate padding